# Mouseenter not working with div jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this div that when the mouse enters it, I want it to show a button within itself. For example here's the code for the div:

```
<div id="menuitem1" style="height: 50px;" class="menuitem">
    <input type="button" class="menuclear" value="Clear" style="margin-left: 10px; display: none;"/>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery code:

```
$(".menuitem").mouseenter(function() {
$(this).next(".menuclear").show();
});
```

This code however doesn't work. I've tried mouseover and hover but still nothing. How do I change the code to make it show the button when the mouse enters the div? It's important to note that I cannot give these items specific id's because there are about thirty other div's and buttons with these same classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` gets the next sibling.  In this case, `.menuclear` is not a sibling, it is a child.  Use `find` or `children` instead:

```
$(".menuitem").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".menuclear").show();
});
```

Comment: Ah thank you much! I knew it would be something simple like that

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works, just the next-function is wrong (it would get the siblings after the element and check them for the given class).

```
$(".menuitem").mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).find(".menuclear").show();
});
```